# Python - Read file and count repeated elements

Tags: python, file, class, for-loop

I have a text file with lists of numbers like this:
1
2 5 3
3 5
4
5
Each number is a node of a tree. When there are more than one numbers in a line, it means that the first number has the following numbers linnked to it.
**1 doesn´t have any numbers after it, so it doesn't have any numbers linked.**
**2 has 3 and 5 linked to it.**
**3 has 5 linked to it and its lnked itself to 2.**
**4 doesn't have any numbers linked to it.**
**5 doesn't have any numbers linked to it, but it's linked to 3 and 2.**
Since 2, 3 and 5 are linked together, they form a component. 1 and 4 are not linked and have no numbers linked to them, so they form a component each.
So, there are 3 components in total.
How would you determine the number of components?
I've had a hard time with **for** loops and conditionals.

```
def components(self):
    elm = 0
    with open('file.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            comp = list(line)
            for x in comp:
                if comp[x] != comp[x+1]:
                    elm += 1
                else:
                    pass
    print(elm)
```

I tried with the code above. I but, when I run it, I get the next message in the function execution:

```
 components missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

It may be necessary to mention that I'm working with classes and I'm barely new to this things.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `self` is a reference to the class of the function. If it is not part of any class, then you need to remove `self` from the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going about this the right way using `for-loops`, but you seem to have gotten a little confused in what you `loop` through! If I understand what you want to achieve correctly, I think I have written the code write to work properly.

With a `text` file named `file.txt` with contents:

```
1
253
35
4
5
```

the following code will create a `list` of `components` and then `print` out how many `components` there are at the end:

```
components = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = [int(i) for i in line.strip()]
        newComponent = True
        for comp in components:
            if not newComponent:
                break
            for ele in line:
                if ele in comp:
                    comp += line
                    newComponent = False
                    break
        components = [list(set(c)) for c in components]
        if newComponent:
            components.append(line)

print(len(components))
```

which outputs what you wanted:

```
3
```

The code starts by first opening the `text` file into `f`. Then we begin our first `loop` which shall go through each `line` in the `file`. We convert this `line` into a `list` of `ints` using a `list-comprehension` on `line.strip()` (`.strip()` just removes the `new-line` `char` from the end.

We then define a `bool` - `newComponents` - which is initialised as `True` as we assume that this `line` will have no `links`.

Next, we `loop` through each `component` in our `list` `components`. The first thing we do here is just quickly check if we have already previously found a `component` that this `line` is `linked` to. If we have, we just `break` out of this `loop`.

Otherwise, if we're not already `linked`, we go through each `element` in our `line` and check if that `element` is in the `component` we are currently `looping` on. If it is, we `concatenate` (with the `+`) our `line` onto that `component`, set out `bool` `newComponent` `flag` false (as we have  a link) and `break` out of this `loop` as we have found a `link`.

After this, the line: `components = [list(set(c)) for c in components]` simply goes through the components and removes `duplicates` from each link. So for instance, if `3` is linked to `2` and we just previously added `3` and `5` to that `component`, there would now be `2` `3s` in that `component` - a duplicate. This line just removes those `duplicates`. Strictly, this line is not necessary as we would still get the same result, but I just thought it would neaten up the code if you wanted to use the `components` later.

Finally, if no `links` were found (`newComponent` is still `True`), we just append this whole `line` (as they are `linked`) to the `components` `list`.

And that's it! We `print()` the length with `len()` at the end and you get your result.

Hope this is of use to you!

#### Update

If the contents of `file.txt` are numbers with multiple digits, you can separate them with a `space`:

```
11
2 45
45 67
8
91
```

then all we have to do is to add in a `.split()` on the end of the `list-comprehension`:

```
components = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split(' ')]
        ...
```

What this does is take the `string` of the `line` and instead of `looping` through each `char` in the `string`, we make a `list` from `splitting` the `string` at each `space` and `iterate` through that. To demonstrate this:

```
"123 456 789".split(" ")
```

gives:

```
["123", "456", "789"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. I just have a question. If I'm working with numbers with more than one digit, what changes should need to be done?

Comment: @Cotton-EyeJoe I will add it to the answer now :)

Comment: @Cotton-EyeJoe Please up-vote and accept if this was useful **:)**